# Looping through each table in a database dropping and creating a trigger

Tags: sql-server, loops, triggers

I have following two statements executing triggers:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers 
      WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID("Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt"))
 DROP TRIGGER Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt ON *myTable*
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO *myTable* (CreatedAt) VALUES(GETDATE())
END
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers 
      WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID("Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt"))
DROP TRIGGER Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt ON *myTable*
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO *myTable* (UpdatedAt) VALUES(GETDATE())
END
GO
```

Now I have found two possibilities to loop through each table in my database
The first one is:

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = myCommand
```

The second one is:

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(300)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
   SELECT NAME
   FROM   SYS.TABLES
   WHERE  TYPE = 'U'
     AND SCHEMA_ID = 1

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @SQL = myCommand

  PRINT @SQL
  EXEC Sp_executesql
    @SQL

  FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR
```

The problem here is that these possibilities do not know the keyword `GO` which I need for executing my commands. 
Is there a possibility to loop through all tables and execute my statement?

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever you think you are doing with this trigger, rethink it. It looks like you are simply attempting to add a `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AT` timestamp for every row. A trigger like this on every table is a sure way to kill performance on your database. You'd be much better off using two columns (one for created_date, one for modified_date) with a default value of `GETDATE()`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171335/computed-column-with-current-datetime/13171375#13171375

Comment: I've already added two columns which are from type GetDate(). Now I need to execute the triggers for creating and modifying

Comment: I still think you should at the very least reconsider the `INSERT` trigger, as that can easily be solved with a `DEFAULT`. I personally would handle the `UPDATE` in the statement, but a trigger could be used to accomplish that.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737945/how-to-create-trigger-for-auto-update-modified-date-with-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of the four parts its own query like this:

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @SQL3 NVARCHAR(300)
DECLARE @SQL4 NVARCHAR(300)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
   SELECT NAME
   FROM   SYS.TABLES
   WHERE  TYPE = 'U'
     AND SCHEMA_ID = 1

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
  SET @SQL1 = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM sys.triggers 
                        WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID(''['+@Name+'_Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt]'')) 
                 DROP TRIGGER ['+@name+'_Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt]'
  SET @SQL2 = 'CREATE TRIGGER ['+ @Name + '_Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt] ON ['+@Name+']
                AFTER INSERT
                AS
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ['+@Name+'] (CreatedAt) VALUES(GETDATE())
                END'
  SET @SQL3 = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
                        FROM sys.triggers 
                        WHERE Object_ID = Object_ID(''['+@Name+'_Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt]''))
                    DROP TRIGGER ['+@name+'_Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt]'
  SET @SQL4 = 'CREATE TRIGGER ['+@Name+'_Insert_Serverdate_Into_UpdatedAt] ON ['+@Name+']
                AFTER UPDATE
                AS
                BEGIN
                INSERT INTO ['+ @Name+'] (UpdatedAt) VALUES(GETDATE())
                END'

  PRINT @SQL1
  EXEC Sp_executesql @SQL1
  PRINT @SQL2
  EXEC Sp_executesql @SQL2
  PRINT @SQL3
  EXEC Sp_executesql @SQL3
  PRINT @SQL4   
  EXEC Sp_executesql @SQL4

  FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Comment: I'm getting: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Insert_Serverdate_Into_CreatedAt'. Same for the other trigger names

Comment: This seems to work partially. In some cases I get Syntax errors like `Incorrect Syntax near (` or `Incorrect Syntax near VALU`. Why?

Comment: Ok I found out. Some of them are just because the statement had to less chars. But what do I do with tables that have spaces or somethin like that in their name? this is not an acceptable trigger name...

Comment: You can uses spaces along as you use square brackets around the table and trigger names. I've updated the answer.