# How to add Constraint to Table's Column,so value cannot be other than default

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

Recently one issue came into my Db,the same db is been shared by multiple Application.

my First application uses one Table to Insert row which was Having A column

`ProductionDate` Of **DataType** `DateTime`
`DateCreated` Of **DataType** `DateTime`  `Default GetDate()`

As we all know `DateCreated`,  will have the time,when Row was inserted to the table when no values are passed in `Insert` Statement

But one of my collegues used the same column `DateCreated` from his application to insert some other value (date ) for the product inspite of using `ProductionDate` (he was misleaded with the name),

i found this issue when my reports was misleading (Select was based on DateCreated).

how can i force my Column to avoid accepting anything ,except it will contain only `Getdate()`,
ie

```
 INSERT INTO MyTableName(.....,DateCreated,......)
 VALUES (.....,'2015-07-15 14:06:42.250',......)
```

Should throw Exception/Error!! I am using SQL SERVER 2012

**Exception**:I Already have an `update/Insert` Trigger to Fill My `DateModified` Column :(

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Triggers can be used to solve this.

Comment: I hate to be the snarky one here, but if your fellow dev has access to the db, there is almost nothing you can do. It's called a design spec and developer communication. Those are the things needed in this situation, not a technical way to prevent one thing from happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rename the existing table (say with an underscore prefix) and replace it with a view using the original name and performing a trivial computation on the `DateCreated` column so that it becomes computed and therefore readonly:

```
create table dbo._T (
    ID int not null,
    DateCreated datetime not null constraint DF_Created DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
go
create view dbo.T
with schemabinding
as
    select ID,COALESCE(DateCreated,DateCreated) as DateCreated
    from dbo._T
go
insert into dbo.T (ID) values (1)
go
insert into dbo.T(ID,DateCreated) values (1,'20150101')
```

Produces:

```
(1 row(s) affected)

Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Update or insert of view or function 'dbo.T' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.
```

And we can see the second insert failed:

```
select * from dbo.T
ID          DateCreated
----------- -----------------------
1           2015-07-07 14:22:48.840
```

And now only give the other user/application permission to talk to this view, not the base table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger to set the date created. Code below taken from [here](http://snipplr.com/view/2595/)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr[TableName]CreateDate ON [TableName]
FOR INSERT 
AS
UPDATE [TableName] SET [TableName].Created=getdate()
FROM [TableName] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [TableName].[UniqueID]= Inserted.[UniqueID]
```

Comment: I already have insertUpdate Column on my Table,so i guess trigger will take it to infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1) You could use an UPDATE TRIGGER to re-set the value of DateCreated to the previous value
2) You could use a rope to tie your collegue to the next tree and teach him the meaning of "DateCreated" :-)

Edit: found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12314601/5089204

Comment: I already have insertUpdate Column on my Table,so i guess trigger will take it to infinite loop

Comment: If you want nothing else than to avoid the update of DateCreated you could use UPDATE-Function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187326(v=sql.120).aspx) within your trigger and throw an error in any case...